# Switch vs If Qual o melhor

Tags: php

galera para trabalhar com números inteiros qual o melhor e o mais leve?
Switch ou If

```
<?php if($lndet['tamanho'] == 0){ ?>
    <td><input type="radio" name="tamanho" id="8.50" value="250GR" required="required"> 250GR </button></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="tamanho" id="10.50" value="400GR" required="required"> 400GR </button></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="tamanho" id="13.50" value="600GR" required="required"> 600GR </button></td>
    <?php }elseif($lndet['tamanho'] == 1) { ?>
    <td><input type="radio" name="tamanho" id="7.50" value="2 RECHEIOS" required="required"> 2 RECHEIOS </button></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="tamanho" id="10.50" value="4 RECHEIOS" required="required"> 4 RECHEIOS </button></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="tamanho" id="14.00" value="6 RECHEIOS" required="required"> 6 RECHEIOS </button></td>
    <?php  }elseif($lndet['tamanho'] == 2){ ?>
```

eu uso dessa forma mostrada acima e ele se repete até o `$lndet['tamanho'] == 30`

está correto ou é melhor usar o Switch?

Comment: Pergunta editada, por favor de uma olhada novamente

Comment: Boa noite, é a terceira vez que digo isto, não use o StackSnippet sem necessidade, veja o real motivo do uso dele: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4463/3635 - tenho certeza que vai entender meu comentário como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: Caso ajude a entender: "stack snippet" é o ícone com `< >` dentro de uma página. O "code" é o ícone com colchetes `{ }`. O primeiro se usa para HTML + JS + CSS autocontidos (que possam ser executados diretamente). O segundo é para todos os outros casos de código (linguagens diferentes de HTML + JS + CSS ou até estes, caso sejam um pedaço isolado que não seja executável). Na dúvida use o ícone `{ }` para formatar seu código.

Comment: Comecei a usar ele porque diversas vezes que eu colocava meu codigo no outro ele simplesmente não exibia.

Comment: @AlfredoLima você devia estar usando o `\`\`` ao invés do Ctrl+K (ou o icone de `{ }`), basta selecionar o texto que é código e apertar Ctrl+K, como eu disse já tem um icone de interrogação do lado quando esta escrevendo que tem dicas de formatação. Espero que as dicas ajudem.

Comment: uma rápida resposta sobre a pergunta: Nenhuma é mais "leve", a diferença de performance raramente vai ser sentida, você deve levar em consideração o caso da necessidade, note que `if` pode fazer coisas que `switch` não pode, no entanto terá vezes que switch será mais pratica (combinar os `cases` por exemplo).

Comment: Você poderia explicar porque esta pergunta não é uma duplicata? Se você acha que não se trata de duplicata (e gostaria de ter a pergunta reaberta), recomendo editar a pergunta explicando o porquê, em especial explicando qual ponderação que você tem e que não é abordada na outra pergunta.